# Insert text characters into image pixels

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a code to insert characters into image with matlab.

The `img` is my cover image and `msg` is my text. I get this error

```
Error using ==> bitset
Operands to BIT Ops must be numeric.
```

But mine is numeric. It is not? How do I make it clear?

```
clear all;
img=imread('img.jpg','jpg');
msgopen=fopen('ramz.txt');
msg=fread(msgopen);
msgbin=dec2bin(msg);
msgsize=size(msg);
x=msgsize(1);
msgsizebin=dec2bin(x,8);
imgh=size(img,1);
imgw=size(img,2);
for i=1:imgh;
  for j=1:imgw;
    img(i,j)=bitset(img(i,j),msgbin(i,1));
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text` function and then the `hardcopy` function to create the image with the text coded into the data;

```
img=imread('img.jpg','jpg');
msgopen=fopen('ramz.txt');
msg=fread(msgopen);
hfig=figure;
imshow(img);
hold on;
text(x_loc,y_loc,msg); %x_loc and y_loc are the locations where you want the text to   
                       % appear. msg is assumed to be a string.
orig_mode = get(hfig, 'PaperPositionMode');
set(hfig, 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto');
img_with_text = hardcopy(hfig, '-Dzbuffer', '-r0');
```

Comment: thaks for ur care,,but i need hide this text in bits of image..in lsb bits...i need use bitset but it gives error...can you please guide me agn?